# Deleting nonexistent queues in RabbitMQ 3+ does not yield expected errors; why?

Tags: rabbitmq, protocols, network-protocols, amqp

**Context:**

We use [RabbitMQ 2.8.5](http://www.rabbitmq.com/release-notes/README-2.8.5.txt), and the [rabbitmq-c](https://github.com/alanxz/rabbitmq-c) client. We decided to upgrade to RabbitMQ 3.2.4 to take advantage of new features/stability/performance.

We don't do anything particularly complicated with RabbitMQ; the most complicated topological construct we have is an alternate exchange, and a two-node mirrored HA cluster. Everything else is standard queues and consumers.

We have some logic regarding the creation/deletion of queues that will occasionally try to delete a non-existent queue (one that has been deleted by another agent in the system). In those cases, we expect to get an AMQP `channel.close` frame in response to the deletion attempt, containing `404 NOT_FOUND` or similar.

**Problem:**

Deletion of nonexistent queues fails as expected against RabbitMQ 2.8.5. However, when we try to delete a nonexistent queue against RabbitMQ 3.2, nothing happens. No error is received, the channel stays open, and a `queue.delete.ok` frame is received.

The problem also occurs with the deletion of exchanges, bindings, etc.

Attempting to *consume* a nonexistent queue, however, yields the expected `404 NOT_FOUND` error.

**What I've Tried:**

1. I repeated all of my tests in a sandbox to ensure that my clients weren't receiving spurious/wrong frames from other broker interactions. Even when mine were the only clients on the RabbitMQ servers in question, the issue persisted.
2. The first thing I did was to isolate the problem. Without using any of our business-specific wrapping around the rabbitmq-c driver, I can reproduce the issue with a script that does the following. The behavior still changes between RabbitMQ versions.

   1. `connect(host, user, port, vhost)`
   2. `channel_open(1)`
   3. `queue_delete(1, "does_not_exist", ) // nowait is defaulted to 0.`
3. Then I tried another driver. I downloaded [AnyEvent::RabbitMQ](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?AnyEvent%3a%3aRabbitMQ) and made a quick Perl script that did the exact same series of operations as my C code did. The behavior was identical to that of my test script.
4. Against the chance that both drivers were doing something wrong, I analyzed the traffic to and from the respective RabbitMQ servers using [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/). The transaction between my client and the old (2.8.5) RabbitMQ server looked the way I expected it to: after `connect`, `tune`, and `channel.open` calls, a `queue.delete` went out, and a `channel.close` containing the 404 NOT_FOUND error code came back near-instantly. When I ran it against the RabbitMQ 3 server, the results were surprising: a `queue.delete.ok` frame was received in response, with a `message-count` field set to 0. The channel remained open, with no indication that my deletion request was invalid. This was true when using the Perl client and the C client.
5. I also tried turning HA/mirroring on and off, respectively, for all queues in the vhosts I was using for testing. The issue did not change.

**Question:**

Why is RabbitMQ 3 confirming deletes on nonexistent queues, and how can I get the old behavior (a channel closure error due to invalid operations) back?

Comment: FWIW, I just checked this on 3.1.3 using C# driver. It definitely returns a 404 like you're looking for. So either it changed in between 3.1.3 and 3.2.4, or it's an option somewhere.

Comment: Excellent info, thanks. I'll start investigating server config/any configurable driver settings.

Comment: Huh, I thought you'd have some response by now. It just occurred to me that you might want to ask this on the RabbitMQ mailing list - I've had decent luck getting answers there. There are many ways to it, Google Groups is one: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/rabbitmq-discuss

Comment: JFYI, deleting exchange is idempotent (has no additional effect if it is called more than once) operation with RabbitMQ broker (https://www.rabbitmq.com/specification.html#method-status-exchange.delete)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve the problem, I basically did a binary search across all RabbitMQ versions between the one we were using and the latest one.

I eventually discovered that this functionality was deliberately added as part of RabbitMQ mainline [enhancement 25716](http://hg.rabbitmq.com/rabbitmq-server/rev/8eaec8dfbc41), in version 3.2.0.

As @zaq178miami pointed out in the comments (very informative, thanks!), the specification violations on the RabbitMQ main site were also updated at this time.

A discussion of the rationale for this is on the RabbitMQ mailing list, [here](http://lists.rabbitmq.com/pipermail/rabbitmq-discuss/2014-January/032970.html).

While this behavior is more "AMQP-ish" than the previous behavior, it will require some refactoring on my part to make my existing code work with newer versions of RabbitMQ

Thanks for all the comments above. For future readers: those comments contain additional useful links regarding this issue.